# Какой IP нужно использовать при создании клиент-серверного приложения?

Tags: ip

Какой IP нужно использовать при создании клиент-серверного приложения?

Comment: Наверное, нужно использовать правильный IP. То есть, непонятно о чем вы спрашиваете :-)

Comment: есть разные версии если смотреть в консоле, с помощью ipconfig

Comment: Использовать где? В клиенте или на сервере? Они на одной машине? В одной сети? Доступен ли сервер клиенту напрямую, или только посредством шлюза с NAT? Знает ли клиент заранее о существовании сервера? Как видите, вопрос вроде бы простой, но на него возможны ну очень разные ответы в зависимости от обстоятельств.

Comment: Клиент и сервер находятся на разных компьютерах, сервер напрямую доступен клиенту, клиент знает о существовании сервера(какой IP использовать в клиенте)

Answer (score 1):

При создании сервера, можно указать ip 0.0.0.0, что будет означать, что сервер будет слушать на всех доступных системе интерфейсах. Либо конкретный ip интерфейса - например, 192.168.1.1

При создании клиента надо указать ip сервера, который будет доступен клиенту на сетевом уровне, а на интерфейсе с этим ip сервер будет слушать/ожидать входящий трафик.